# How to navigate pressing <enter> on a SearchResult rendered as Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, semantic-ui-react

I've managed to render SearchResult (of [Search](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/) component) as Link ([react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)) which obviously has a "to" prop.

If I click on a search result, it works as expected: the browser changes to the URL specified by "to" prop.

But, If I navigate between the search results with up and down arrows and then press enter on one of them, router navigation doesn't work.

Any thoughts on that? Any solutions?

Comment: `If I navigate between the search results with up and down arrows`. How are you doing that? is there code that is catching keypresses?

Comment: I type some text into the Search component and a list or results is rendered.

Then, I move between them with up and down arrows (the active search result becomes gray, to indicate that it is in focus), then I press <enter> to visit that link. But no!

No, I don't have any code catching keypresses, as I expect it to behave as a normal "a" element when navigating with <tab> and pressing <enter>.

Please, take a look [here](https://imgur.com/mSSzdOE). Maybe it helps a little!

Comment: Do you have something somewhere else that is capturing keypresses? if you `preventDefault` it may be stopping your enter

Comment: No I don't.

In general, when an "a" element is focused, the browser shows a popup on the bottom left corner which contains the destination. See [this](https://imgur.com/l46b6OB). The card is also a Link.

When I focus on a search result, it doesn't. Which means that the "a" is not focused.

Comment: I understand how the browser works :) It sounds like the focus is on the wrong element, maybe define a `tabindex` on the elements to make sure it focuses the correct element

Comment: Unfortunately, specifying the tabindex doesn't work either.